# How can I improve the Android developer documentation?

Tags: android

I have noticed some grammatical errors in the developer version of Android official documentation. How may I notify the Android documentation team about this? There is no link to contact or present a copy of the corrected documentation in the page.

The page is this:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#defining

Thanks everyone for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You are welcome to file an issue on [the issue tracker](http://b.android.com/).